# Comparing string in CSV header against expected value yields not equal when debug log shows they are identical

Tags: string, csv

I'm reading a CSV file saved in a ContentVersion

The CSV header looks like:

```
FirstName,LastName,...
```

I'm checking to make sure the first line (header row) matches the expected column headers using this code:

```
ContentVersion cv = [SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ...];
String csv = cv.VersonData.toString();
String[] csvHeader;
//  apply CSV Parser to csv to read first line into a array of cells csvHeader (not shown)
if (!csvHeader[0] == 'FirstName') {
  throw new MyException('Header does not match expected value FirstName in column A');
}
```

But the CSV header displays in the debug log as having a value of `FirstName` in array position 0.

Why does the string compare fail?  `FirstName` == `FirstName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took a while to figure out. Here's what I did:

- I copy-pasted the actual CSV row header `FirstName` and the expected CSV row header `FirstName`  into two cells in Excel and then wrote a formula to see if they were equal. They were not! But why?
- I then copy-pasted the actual CSV row header `FirstName` into a hex editor. My, my, what did I see but these hex characters:

  ```
   EF BB BF 46 69 72 73 74 4E 61 6D 65
            F  i  r  s  t  N  a  m  e
  ```

`EF BB BF` is a [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and was added to the CSV file during the Excel save process (not the upload into a `ContentVersion`)

So, the code needed to be changed to remove the BOM before comparison

```
ContentVersion cv = [SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ...];
String csv = cv.VersonData.toString().removeStart('\uFEFF'); // remove BOM
String[] csvHeader;
//  apply CSV Parser to csv to read first line into a array of cells csvHeader (not shown)
if (!csvHeader[0] == 'FirstName') { 
  throw new MyException('Header does not match expected value FirstName in column A');
}
```

**Lesson** - when two strings that look the same in the debug log compare unequal; paste them into a [hex editor](https://hexed.it/) and see the true values.

Comment: And, of course, make sure you only remove it if it's present.

Comment: `removeStart`: `Removes the specified substring only if it occurs at the beginning of the String.`

Comment: I would have just removed it from the original string before splitting and everything else as a matter of legibility. Didn't say you were doing it wrong.

Comment: ah, good point; i'll fix